# How to determine hypothesis and evidence in Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

I am new to Bayes theorem, and bit confused how to identify evidence and hypothesis in the theorem.For e.g.I have this problem - in a company 10% of laptops fail within their warranty period. 5% of the people in the company work in the Sales department.15% of the laptops that fail within their warranty period belonged to Sales employees.Now a new employee X has just joined the Sales department and gotten a laptop. He wants to know how likely it is that his laptop will fail within the warranty period. How I will determine that? Will it be like below -

```
A= A laptop will fail within warranty
B= A person is working in the Sales department
P(A) = probability a laptop working will fail within warranty
P(B) = probability a laptop working in sales
P(A|B) = Probability that a laptop will fail within warranty given the person is working in Sales


P(A|B) = P(B|A) P(A) / P(B)
```

Person working in sales is evidence and laptop failure is hypothesis?

Comment: Many people find it helpful to think in terms of actual numbers rather than probabilities.  Here, for example, we can imagine a company of 2000 people with laptops of whom 100 are in sales.  We are told that 10% of 2000 = 200  laptops fail under warranty and 15% of those 200 = 30 belong to salespeople.  If you are asked to give an opinion about a typical salesperson's laptop, then, what would you say about its chances of failure under warranty? Would you stop to ask "what is hypothesis and what is evidence," or could you get straight to an answer?

Comment: will it be 30/ total number of sales people in this case?